# Docker Ubuntu cannot stat 'keys/id_rsa' no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I successfully added my shh key and I copied it from the original file to the folder keys however it cant access to it

[image]

My dockerfile :

```
FROM wernight/phantomjs
#Install casperjs WORKDIR /home

WORKDIR /home
USER root
RUN (apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git socat python dnsutils )

RUN git clone https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
RUN mv /home/casperjs /usr/local/share/casperjs-latest
RUN ln -sf /usr/local/share/casperjs-latest/bin/casperjs /usr/local/share/casperjs
RUN ln -sf /usr/local/share/casperjs-latest/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
RUN ln -sf /usr/local/share/casperjs-latest/bin/casperjs /usr/bin/casperjs
ADD /home/afaf/reworldmedia-network/keys/id_rsa  /home/afaf/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD /home/afaf/reworldmedia-network/keys/id_rsa.pub  /home/afaf/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ADD start.sh /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT /start.sh
```

Comment: your Dockerfile would help a lot

Comment: yes, and add please `entrypoint.sh` and root directory structure

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the following lines to the file docker-compose.yml

```
tty: true 
stdin_open: true
```

Also I removed the file /var/run/docker.sock and restarted docker services